# Choice of random in RSA-KEM

Tags: rsa, key-generation, kem

This may be nit-picking, I’m not sure so feel free to say so.

In RSA-KEM as described e.g. in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation#Example_using_RSA_encryption) or [this answer](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/70557/76344), we choose a secret $x : 0 \leq x < n$, and send $x^e \bmod n$ for public exponent $e$.

But isn’t this “textbook RSA”? For example, if $x^e \bmod n < n$ then it won’t wrap, and $x$ can be obtained directly.

Now of course for any normal $n$, the chances of choosing a random $x$ meeting this condition are infinitesmally small. Nevertheless isn’t it technically precise to choose  $x: x < n$, $x^e \bmod n > n$ ?

Comment: Related questions (but which do not directly address my question) https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/53232/rsa-kem-minimal-number-of-random-bits, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/34041/bitwise-method-of-generating-r-for-rsa-kem, https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/76089/why-rsa-kem-is-more-secure-than-textbook-rsa

Comment: @kelalaka IIUC the answer there is it's mathematically imprecise, but it is indeed nit-picking

Comment: @kelalaka So shall I delete my question?

Comment: No need, it has already been closed; having a dupe may lead other persons looking for the same Q/A to the right answer.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes yes, you are right, however, I did not like the title change of the dupe!